# Problems with boot when external monitor is connected (once more!)

Tags: boot, multiple-monitors

Please: I'm a linux newcomer!

During the last few days I have been working hard to make my system stable. After several re-installations, I conclude that my major issue is related with my external monitor.

Without it, the things are running smoothly. But when I connect it, the boot fails (black screen).

I see others asking about the same issue (years ago), but with no answers. So, please, what can I do?

My notebook is an ASUS 7265 with Nvidia 960M. I had purged and re-installed the drivers several times, until conclude the 'guilty' is the external monitor. Without the external monitor, the systems works fine with the xserver-xorg-video-noveau driver, or with the Nvidia 460 driver. After connect the external monitor... boot fails anyway (black screen).

A curious fact is that when the external monitor is connected during the boot, the system chooses the external monitor to start with instead the build in one. I guess this is the issue, but have no idea how to fix it!

HELP!!!